# Echo only once td for specific row

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to display only once group but names and years to list all.
Bellow is my php code:

```
  <?php $sql = "SELECT * FROM users where users_group = 'soccer'"; 
$result = mysql_query($sql); while ($ok=mysql_fetch_object($result)){?>

<table>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $ok->user_group;?></td>
<td><?php echo $ok->name;?></td>
<td><?php echo $ok->years;?></td>
</tr>
</table> <?php } ?>
```

How do i echo only once user group that is in same user group ?
Here is drawing, sory for bad hand.
http://s13.postimg.org/icmso13vb/example.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could save the group to a var and compare with that in the next loop. If group has changed you can output it, if not prevent the output.

EDIT:

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users where users_group = 'soccer'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$lastGroup = '';
while ($ok = mysql_fetch_object($result)) {
?>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo($lastGroup == $ok->user_group ? '' : $ok->user_group); ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $ok->name; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $ok->years; ?></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
<?php
$lastGroup = $ok->user_group;
}
?>
```

BTW: You shouldn't use `mysql_query` as it is deprecated since PHP 5.3 and removed in PHP 7. Use at least msqli or better use PDO.

Comment: Yes but having problems making it. I know i could use group by and solve problems but i would like to learn like this..